# Retrieve AzureAD Users sign-in logs Kusto Resource Graph Query

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-explorer, azure-resource-graph

I am trying to get a list of users logged into azure AD, that can be seen under Users | All Users from the azure portal, using Kusto Resource Graph Query but does anybody know how to call this? i understand i can List all sign-ins via http response

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns

but how do i call this in Resource Graph?

I know i can call resources to Show a List resources sorted by name

e.g

```
Resources
| project name, type, location
| order by name asc
```

and can call

```
resources
| where identity contains "userAssignedIdentities"
```

but all im returning is user assigned identities.. and not Users i.e User Type, User Principle Name, Name, Account Enabled, Company etc

that should be specific to All Users and Signin-Logs

any help would be appreciated

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You can pull the signin logs of users using kusto query -- for that you need to few prerequisite***

1. You should have Secuirity admin or global admin Permission.
2. Creating a log analytics workspace.
3. Setting diagnostic settings.

You can follow this ***[Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-log-analytics-wizard#configure-a-workspace)*** to create log analytics workspace and add in `ActiveDirectory->Diagnotics Setting`.

[image]

***You can use the below Kusto Query in AzureActiveDirectory->Log Analytics***

```
SigninLogs
| project UserId,UserType,UserDisplayName
```

[image]
[image]

***Note : There is not option to project AccountEnable,Company***

Comment: cheers bud, this looks ace i cannot seem to view log analytics in our tenant.. think i need to be assigned user global administrator or security administrator as i just seem to see "Log Analytics integration not enabled This Azure AD tenant is not currently enabled to send logs to Log Analytics. Please click the link below to learn about how to turn on this feature." even when i create a new workspace.. will update when i have access

Answer (score 0):

Yep this works bud, also changing my permission to security admin.. many thanks